# Trigonometric polynomial with exactly 2N zeroes

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I have proved that a trigonometric polynomial of the form $\sum^{N}_{n=-N}c_ne^{inx}$ has at most 2N zeroes with the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Now I am asked to find a trigonometric polynomial with exactly 2N zeroes. Here I got stuck, I have no idea how to approach this problem. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Clarification: can the zeros be any complex number or are they restricted in some way? Assuming they can be any complex number, here's a starting point: pick your favorite ordinary polynomial of degree $2N$ with $2N$ zeroes (let's say they're distinct for simplicity). Require that none of the zeros are located at zero. Do you see where to go from there?

Comment: @Ian, I guess the x should be in $[-/pi,/pi], otherwise the statement that the trigonometric polynomial has at most 2N zeroes does not make sense.

Comment: And do you mean something like P(x)=(x-1)...(x-2N)? I already thought of this but do not know if I can use this as a 'trigonometric polynomial'

Comment: I think that the hint @Ian tried to give you has to do with the fact that every complex number has n distinct n-th roots. See if you can work with that!

Comment: My clarifying question was basically about whether $x$ needs to be in a $[-\pi,\pi)$ or if it can be in $\{ x + i y: x \in [-\pi,\pi),y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. If it needs to be in $[-\pi,\pi)$ then you need to ensure that the zeroes are of modulus $1$ rather than just being any nonzero complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your favorite $2N$ complex numbers of modulus $1$, say $e^{ix_1},...e^{ix_{2N}}, x_k \in [0, 2\pi)$ and consider $e^{-iNx}\Pi_{n=1}^{2N}(e^{ix}-e^{ix_n})=\sum_{n=-N}^Nc_ke^{ikx}$

By construction, it is a trigonometric polynomial of degree $2N$ with the roots in the period interval $[0, 2\pi)$ being precisely $x_k$